# Add specific method handler detail_route in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an API built with Django Rest Framework. There's a `ViewSet` in it with `detail_route`s I'm trying to handle nested data with:

```py
from rest_framework.mixins import (RetrieveModelMixin, CreateModelMixin, 
                                   ListModelMixin)
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet

class UserViewSet(RetrieveModelMixin, CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin, 
                  GenericViewSet)

    ...

    @detail_route(methods=['get'], url_path='photos')
    def photos(self, request):
        return Response(self.get_photos())

    @detail_route(methods=['post'], url_path='photos')
    def new_photo(self, request, pk=None):
        a_new_photo = Photo(user=self.request.user)
        serializer = PhotoSerializer(data=request.data,
                                     instance=new_photo)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data,
                            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So my intention is to have this `ViewSet` to handle both `GET` and `POST` requests to a url like this:

```
/api/users/42/photos
```

Where `GET` will return a list of photos for user id #42 and `POST` will add a new photo to this user.

However, this view handles only one method: `POST`. For `GET` it returns an error:

```py
{"detail":"Method \\"GET\\" not allowed."}
```

How do I handle each HTTP method separately with `detail_route`?

Debugging doesn't show any obvious overrides when I output routes for this view:

```py
Route(url=u'^{prefix}/{lookup}/photos{trailing_slash}$', mapping={'post': 'new_photo'}, name=u'{basename}-photos', initkwargs={})
Route(url=u'^{prefix}/{lookup}/photos{trailing_slash}$', mapping={'get': 'photos'}, name=u'{basename}-photos', initkwargs={})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to handle both `GET` and `POST` with one `detail_route`-decorated handler and to do additional dispatching inside the handler:

```py
@detail_route(methods=['get', 'post'])
def photos(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return self.new_photo(request)

    return Response(self.get_photos())
```

Comment: On similar lines, is it possible to add both list_route and details route with same name?